# Constructing base class by moving derived one

Tags: c++, move

I have this simplified code example:

```
class Base {
    Base() = default;
    Base(const Base& src) {
        // construct by copying src etc. - ok, legal even if src points to Derived object
    }

    Base(Base&& src) {
        // construct by moving src - stealing its resources, ok, it was invented for this, 
        // but.. what if src points to Derived object?
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {

};

void foo() {
    Derived derived;
    Base base_by_copy_constructor(derived); // legal, derived cannot be touched so nothing will be wrong
    Base base_by_move(std::move(derived)); // uu? what's gonna happen, part of derived object (Base class) was moved..
}
```

Is such a behaviour proper? That can lead to weird problems because Base part od Derived object was actually 'deinitialized'.
So.. Should we avoid deriving from class which has move operator, or make our Derived class resistant to 'moving' its base part?

(Of course - this is only example, classes have no data, move operator does not do anything, so here nothing will go wrong. I'm asking about a real world example of such a.. situation :) )

Comment: It will lead to *object slicing*.

Comment: I guess this is a new item in the growing list of "don't slice your objects, or else".

Comment: moved object should be in a valid state afterward, So there is no real issue.

Comment: A properly written move-constructor would set `Base` to a state similar to `Base() = default;`, which `Derived` may or may not be able to handle. So "It depends".

Comment: When you have a polymorphic tree of classes then you have to manage and to pass resulting objects with (possibly smart) pointers to those. So =delete or protect copying and moving and if you need copies make virtual function clone that returns pointer. Rest of the copies/moves must be responsibility of those pointers not objects.

Comment: @ÖöTiib OP's classes are not polymorphic, as they are defined here.

Comment: @DanielLangr you are correct, OP classes do nothing and have nothing. I was only offering opinion for certain case when there will be something and the classes do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their is no problem with slicing, this can be done explictly and intensionnaly.

Nevertheless when dooing OO programming in general, there is only one rule de follow: *Do not let the possibility to any entity which is external to your object(or component) have the opportunity to break invariants.*

So if invoking a member or a constructor of the base class could break an invariant that your derived class establish between it and its base, so the base must be private. (You can still bring public the members of the base that do not break invariants with `using base::member`)